# Is there a technical reason why an enumerator is not a literal?

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer, c++20, literals

I thought that the [enumerator](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#nt:enumerator)s of an `enum [class]` were [literals](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal.kinds#nt:literal), because, to my understanding, they represent for their `enum [class]` what `1` represents for `int`, `true` for `bool`, and `"hello"` for `char const*`. However, they are not, because the standard lists only these literals,

```
literal:
    integer-literal
    character-literal
    floating-point-literal
    string-literal
    boolean-literal
    pointer-literal
    user-defined-literal
```

whereas the word *literal* doesn't occur at all in [[dccl.enum]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#nt:enumerator).

Is there a reason why the standard doesn't classify enumerators as literals of the enumeration type they belong to?

Comment: "Literal" is a syntactical concept, not a semantical one; it can be detected from its syntactical form alone, from the characters it consists of. Syntactically, the enumerator is an identifier; it's not obvious that it's in fact an enumerator until name lookup is performed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a technical reason why an enumerator is not a literal?

You'll notice that the term "literal" is defined in the C++ standard chapter "Lexical conventions". "Lexical" here refers to [Lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), which takes a sequence of characters and generates a sequence of tokens. These tokens then undergo grammatical processing.

C++ defines various classes of tokens. Among these are keywords, operators, punctuation, identifiers, and yes literals. But that's all a literal is: a kind of token. A classification of the lexical analysis of a sequence of characters.

An enumerator is not the product of lexical analysis of characters; it's the product of *syntactic* analysis of a sequence of tokens. Consider this sequence of text: `name1::name2`. Lexically, you know what this is: it's an identifier followed by the `::` operator, followed by an identifier.

Grammatically however... you have no idea. Maybe `name1` designates a class and `name2` is a member of that class. Maybe `name1` is a namespace and `name2` is a member of that namespace. Or... maybe `name1` is an *enumeration* and `name2` is an enumerator within that enumeration.

You cannot know just from the sequence of text in isolation. Syntax is a matter of context, and without context, all you have is a bunch of tokens.

An enumerator cannot be a literal because the determination of what is or is not an enumerator is a product of a process that happens after the determination of what is and is not a literal.